# Group records by year, having start and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to build a graph that will show enable projects by year, example:

A project has a start_date in 04-06-2014 and a end_date in 07-09-2016, so the project is enabled in 2014, 2015 and 2016.

How could I build a query to fetch this records grouping by year, since the project can count in different years?

Comment: Until now I was trying to manage it through Ruby, getting the last year and the newest year to get a range, doing a foreach on this years range. After that I was going to try to check if the year of the start_date is less or equal of the year(range) and the year of end_date was higher or equal of the year(range), and count it. But since it will generate a lot of hits in database. I am trying to find a way to do it in one Select.

Comment: One way to do it is to generate a list of years (either have a function return each year or just insert records into a table).  Then you join your table against this record set including whichever records belong with that year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide enough information... Nevertheless, the basic idea is to use aggregate functions, such as:

```
SELECT YEAR(date_field) As MyYear, SUM(numeric_field) AS MyValue
FROM TableName
WHERE (start_date_field >= '2014-04-06' AND  end_date_field <= '2016-07-09')
GROUP BY YEAR(date_field)
```

For further information, please see:
[Date and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
[Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)